# Binding data to a ListBox and posting the list to database mvc5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, html.listboxfor

Im developing an mvc5 application with code first approach. In one of my views i have a textbox, a add button, a save button, a delete button and a listbox.

When i enter a value in textbox(a text) and click add button it should be added to the listbox and show the text. Hence there'll be multiple text in this listbox. And also i should be able to delete a record/records in listbox using delete button.

After that i want to post this list to server. Majority of tasks in this scenario can be done using Jquery i suppose.

upto now what i have done

in _AttributeCreate partial view

```
@model eKnittingData.AttributeViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Attribute"))
{ 
   @Html.TextBox("abc")
   <input type="button" name="AddText" value="Add Text" id="AddText" />

    @Html.ListBoxFor(a => a.typevalue, new SelectList(Model.typevalue, "Id", "Text"))


    <input type="submit" value="Save" id="btn" class="btn btn-success" onclick="disableBtn()" />
}
```

script to append items

```
<script>
        $('#AddText').click(function () {
            $('#typevalue').append(
                new Option($('input[name=abc]').val()));
        });  
</script>
```

AttributeViewModel

```
public class AttributeViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<String> typevalue { get; set; }
}
```

But this is not working. Pls guide me on how to do this(including delete functionality and final post functionailty). Thanks in advance!

Comment: You current code does not make sense. `typevalue` is `IEnumerable<string>` so you cannot use `new SelectList(Model.typevalue, "Id", "Text"` - a `string` does not contain properties `Id` and `Text`. Which bit are you struggling with? and what is `onclick="disableBtn()"`?

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke, Thanks for replying :) I want to do the exact as my question. I thought that "Id" and "Text" refers to the sequence number and text of a particular entry in the list. I want to insert some texts to listbox. There many other fields in this view but i briefed it and put only relevant here. Pls ignore onclick since i mistakenly put it here. Im struggling with binding data to listbox via the textbox and submitting the final list toDB. I am failing to develop correct jquery scripts for this. Thanks for helping me...

Comment: `$('#typevalue').append($('<option></option>').text($('#abc').val()));` will add a new option to the listbox. But I'm not sure you understand how a `<select multiple>` works - it only posts back the values of the selected options so unless you specifically select some or all of them, nothing will post back.

Comment: Im getting 'value cannot be null' error from listboxfor helper when im trying to render this view. How should the listbox be coded in the view? yes im not aware of<select multiple>. I want to post the whole list without selecting. The way i have put listboxfor in view is wrong i suppose. Pls help me to correct this.

Comment: That's because of your `new SelectList(Model.typevalue, "Id", "Text")` I noted earlier. It should be just ``new SelectList(Model.typevalue)` but even that is not the correct way of doing it. You should have one property for the selected items and one property for the options to initially display

Comment: But none of this will really work anyway because all your scripts need to be constantly re-select all options. I suspect what you really want is to add a new readonly textbox on each button click (or a hidden input and display text) with an associated 'delete' button. Hard to understand what the point of using a listbox is in this case.

Comment: There are many other fields in this view. Once we submit, those values are submitted to a table and values(texts) in the listbox submitted to another table which has a FK relationship with the previous table i mentioned. yes the listbox is only to show those added values. I thought it would be appropriate for this scenario. Is there any other easy way of doing this?

Comment: Yes, just dynamically create a new input with `name="typevalue"` and add it to the form. And include an associated 'delete' button to remove it. If you need an example I can add an answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes pls provide me an example. I should be able show the values to user once he inserted it through textbox. So that all values can be seen by user in some container before user submit it. User should be able to delete a record/records by selecting one or more. Thanks for helping me..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91550/discussion-between-isuru-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues with you code and implementation. `@Html.ListBoxFor(a => a.typevalue, new SelectList(Model.typevalue, "Id", "Text"))` will not work because `typevalue` is `IEnumerable<String>` and `string` does not contain properties named `Id` and `Text`. While you could just use `@Html.ListBoxFor(a => a.typevalue, null)` a listbox is not appropriate from what your trying to do. A listbox (`<select multiple>` element) only posts back the values of its selected options so unless all options are selected when the form is submitted, you will not get the results you expect.

From the comments you are wanting to dynamically add new items to add to the `typevalue` collection, and have the ability to delete them. Your html should be something like

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Attribute"))
{
  <input type="text" id="newtypevalue" />
  <input type="button" value="Add Text" id="addtypevalue" />
  <div id="typevaluelist">
    // Generate inputs for existing items and in case of returning the view
    foreach(var item in Model.typevalue)
    {
      <div class="typevalue">
        <input type="text" name="typevalue" value="@item" />
        <button type="button" class="delete">Delete</button>
      </div>
    }
  </div>
  ....
}
// Hidden template for adding new items (outside the form element)
<div id="new" style="display:none;">
  <div class="typevalue">
    <input type="text" name="typevalue" />
    <button type="button" class="delete">Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

and add the following scripts for adding and deleting items

```
$('#addtypevalue').click(function() {
  var clone = $('#new').clone().children('div'); // copy the template
  clone.find('input').val($('#newtypevalue').val()); // update text
  $('#typevaluelist').append(clone); // add it to the DOM
  $('#newtypevalue').val(''); // clear initial text box
});
$('#typevaluelist').on('click', '.delete', function() {
  $(this).closest('.typevalue').remove(); // remove it from the DOM
});
```

Refer [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/csf5hdyd/)

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke, Sorry for the late reply.. There was a power failure today and couldn't attend the question after that. Anyways thanks a lot for the solution. Tomorrow i'll update you regarding this.

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke, I refereed the fiddle and yes i would like to go with that.  I tried your solution. At 'foreach(var item in Model.typevalue)' im getting the error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'. But i have created a object of viewmodel in the controller and binded it to a viewdata since im passing it through the partialview. Could you pls tell me what would be the issue?

Comment: That would be because `typevalue` is null. If you initially start with no elements, then you at least need to initialize it as an empty list in the controller before you pass the model to the view - e.g. `var model = new AttributeViewModel() { typevalue = new List<string> }; return View(model);`

Comment: Yes that was the issue. Now it is working perfectly. Thank you. I need another help also. Now i want to capture all these texts and send them to database(each record as a separate raw in the table). Could you pls help me to achieve this?

Comment: Sure, but you need to ask a new question with a bit more detail :)

Comment: Ok i'll put it as new question now.. Thanks :)

Comment: I would like to improve my knowledge regarding implementation of a ListBox for this kind of scenario. And that knowledge will be useful in future as well. If you could, pls provide me a link or some resource for that..

Comment: Using a ListBox is not good for this scenario and I don't know of any 'good' articles, probably because ListBox  is not a good control (some users are confused by it) and its difficult if there are many items so that users have to constantly scroll to see what is selected and what is not - refer [this article](http://doejo.com/solutions-for-implementing-user-friendly-multi-select/) for some extra info.

Comment: Thanks for the information.. I'll refer that article :)

Comment: Could you pls help me.. I want to restrict user adding the same text(a existing value in the list) to dyanamic textbox. I tried it like this in view. foreach(var item in Model.typevalue){if(!Model.typevalue.Contains(item)){<div>....</div>}}. But this is not working. Pls help me with the correct way. Thanks :)

Comment: @Isuru, Its not that hard to solve but you need to ask a new question. This one has already been answer and we can't just keep going forever.